# How to get a list of accounts that are not assigned to any territory?

Tags: account, territory

I found out that we have accounts without any territory assigned. How can I get a list of all accounts with that problem?

It is not possible to create a roll-up summary field, as the relationship is not a parent-child relationship.

A possibility is to create an Apex script that loops over all ObjectTerritory2Association objects, gathers a set of unique account ids and subtracts that set from the total set of accounts. But that is something I would like to avoid.

Comment: It's a bit like what you suggested, but could you simply use two SOQL queries: `List<ObjectTerritory2Association> otas = [SELECT ObjectId FROM ObjectTerritory2Association]; Set<Id> accounts = new Set<Id>(); for (ObjectTerritory2Association ota : otas) { accounts.put(ota.ObjectId); } List<Account> unmappedAccounts = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id NOT IN :accounts];`

Comment: Thanks. BTW One correction: put should be add.

Comment: Yeah, one of those "writing code in a text input" moments... is this a worthy solution to your issue? Should I post it as an answer?

Comment: Yes, I have used it in absence of a solution with reports. So feel free to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I would suggest is one that is akin to your final paragraph, though that avoids explicit Apex subtraction of the associated Accounts from the total set of Accounts by using SOQL to do this for you:

```
List<ObjectTerritory2Association> otas = [SELECT ObjectId FROM ObjectTerritory2Association];
Set<Id> accounts = new Set<Id>();

for (ObjectTerritory2Association ota : otas) {
    accounts.add(ota.ObjectId);
}

List<Account> unmappedAccounts = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id NOT IN :accounts];
```

At this point `unmappedAccounts` includes only those Accounts that have no ObjectTerritory2Association mapping.

Note that this will have issues if you have a very large number of Accounts (with or without associations) since governor limits apply and/or SOQL may complain about an unselective query.